# python to wait for shell command to complete

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, wait

I am running script to unrar some files and the remove the rar files afterwards. 
I am doing this by running the command through shell. I have tried several different ways to make the script wait until it's done unpacking the files, but it still goes ahead and deletes the file before they are done being used.

I have tried the code below, which is a no go. I have tried to see if i could get the wait() to work, but also no luck.

Any ideas?
running python 2.7

EDIT: I want the script to run the command :)

```
            p = subprocess.Popen('unrar e ' + root + '/' + i + ' ' + testfolder,
                                 bufsize=2048, shell=True,
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            p.stdin.write('e')
            p.communicate()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(testfolder):
    for i in files:

        print 'Deleting rar files'
        os.remove(i)

for i in os.listdir(testfolder):
    if os.path.isdir(testfolder + i):
        shutil.rmtree(testfolder + i)
```

Comment: if you wait for the command, you don't need `subprocess`

Comment: I would like to make my script run the command.

Comment: `os.system("some command")` is blocking afaik .... so it should block until unrar returns at least (which I assume is when it is finished) ... although i would think subproccess.communicate is also blocking ... my guess is that unrar does not wait until its finished to return an exit code

Comment: @KarolyHorvath However, using `subprocess.Popen` is far safer than using `os.system()`, as it's capable of being used without a shell. (Granted, it's not being used that way HERE, but that's bad practice and unsafe).

Answer (score 6):

This is evil:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('unrar e ' + root + '/' + i + ' ' + testfolder,
        bufsize=2048, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Instead,

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['unrar', 'e', '%s/%s' % (root, i), testfolder],
        bufsize=2048, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('e')
p.wait()
if p.returncode == 0:
    pass # put code that must only run if successful here.
```

By passing an exact array rather than a string to `Popen` and not using `shell=True`, a filename with a space in it can't be interpreted as a more than one arguments, or a subshell command, or some other potentially malicious thing (think of a file with `$(rm -rf ..)` in its name).

Then, after calling `p.wait()` (there's no need for `p.communicate()` when you aren't capturing stderr or stdout), you must check `p.returncode` to determine whether the  process was successful, and only  proceed on to delete files if `p.returncode == 0` (indicating success).

Your initial diagnosis, that `p.communicate()` is returning while the `unrar` process is still running, is not feasible; `p.communicate()` and `p.wait()` do not work that way.

---

If running across `ssh`, this changes a bit:

```
import pipes # in Python 2.x; in 3.x, use shlex.quote() instead
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', ' '.join(
      [pipes.quote(s) for s in ['unrar', 'e', '%s/%s' % (root, i), testfolder]])
```

Comment: You may need `p.stdin.close()` before `p.wait()`, otherwise if your program waits for EOF your code will hang waiting for the sub-process.

Comment: Also, if the sub-process is `ssh`, I am seeing that even using the second form I still have to add quotes around arguments with spaces or else the remote system doesn't see them as a single argument.

Comment: @Michael, ssh does a remote round of expansion in addition to the local expansion that using this technique correctly avoids. If you want to prepare commands for ssh, use `pipes.quote()` (or, in Python 3.x, `shlex.quote()`) to escape your arguments.

Comment: @Michael, ...I've expanded the answer to directly address that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem waiting on the subprocess, or doing the things in order (meaning unpacking, then deleting).

If your problem is waiting on  the subprocess, then you should check out the function `subprocess.call`

Check:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

That function blocks until the other process terminates.

If your problem however is unpacking the files, and you don't necesarrily have to use subprocessess, then just check out any other lib for unpacking, like pyunrar2:

- https://code.google.com/p/py-unrar2/

or this other one:

- https://python-unrar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: My problem is i want it to finish unpacking first and then delete the files. right now it moves on to delete the files before it can finish unpacking.

Comment: then just use `subprocess.call()` instead of `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: @vlad-ardelean Using `subprocess.call()` is incompatible with needing to write a character to the command's stdin, as the original code does.